# Windows Mobile Facebook app news feed shows all my friends

Tags: facebook

I have whittled down my news feed on Facebook to show me updates from the friends I really care about.  When I view Facebook on my Windows mobile device, I get everybody.  Apparently, I even get updates from The Office since I listed that as a TV Show or something.

Can I pare down the news feed on my mobile device so it shows me only the friends that I see on the web application?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your iPhone then no you cannot pair them down.  Your only option is to select what type of feed you want to read (posts, photos, games, etc) but you have to do it everything single time you open the Facebook App.  I agree it sucks but Facebook has done nothing to fix it in the past 2 years.